# Use of the certificate with private key not marked as exportable

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl-certificate

I would like to know what is the use of certificate of which private key is not marked as epxortable. I saw that while sending a certificate request from Internet Explorer to a certificate server, it gives option to mark the key as not exportable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a common usage scenario to create a non-exportable private key when creating a certificate request *unless* this key goes directly to the hardware (USB token and alike). Yet, it's possible for example when machine-bound certificates are created in corporate environments. In this case it's better to mark the certificate as non-exportable - if the machine is gone, you can issue new certificate for new machine and block (revoke) the previous one.

Usually non-exportable keys are used when you import the existing certificate with a private key - non-exportable flag is set for security reason.

Comment: Can you list down some threats if the key is exportable? Also, how does Internet Explorer makes the use of such private key?

Comment: CryptoAPI lets you perform signing and decryption using such keys - surely for the OS the keys are accessible. And the threat is that the key can be stolen.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. This is what I guess after seeing functions such as CryptSignMessage which let you sign the message without exporting the key provided that cryptographic provider of the certificate. In Internet Explorer, SSL/TLS is implemented using WinSock and Crypt32 (This is what I guess). In Mutual SSL Handshake, it only needs to sign the data which it can do using CryptoAPI, that is why it makes the use of certificate even with key is marked as non-exportable. Please correct me if I am wrong and please confirm it.

Comment: @dbasic yes, your understanding is correct. Still for client-side authentication (in "mutual SSL handshake") it's a bit risky (from management point of view) to have the certificate's private key be non-exportable if you don't have its backup. The better idea is to mark the key as exportable, obtain the certificate, export it to PFX, then delete from the system together with the key and finally re-import it as non-exportable from PFX. This way you get a backup copy.